# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in NGINX for one specific domain

Tags: nginx, cors

I have problem with my nginx configuration. I want to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in nginx config, for one domain but for both **http** and **https**

I tried this configuration, but it doesn't work:

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "https://example.com http://example.com" always;`

I get error response from browser:

`The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://example.com http://example.com', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value ?`

Answer (score 3):

Use [nginx's `$scheme`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_scheme) variable

> $scheme
>
> request scheme, “http” or “https”

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "${scheme}://example.com" always;
```